# Internal Error PyWin32 with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I written a simple script in Python using Tkinter. When I try to build an executable using Pyinstaller with the following command: `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed  frontend.py` the console return this message *"Internal error: early pywin32 import was introduced"*.

I'm using Python 3.6 and since Pyinstaller doesn't support the recent version of Python I use the DEV distribution.

Thanks in advance for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is a bug introduced in the last commit 3e14224.
See the discussion here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/commit/3e142240d95ad3061593185bfbf6f602e4be39af
You could try to check out an earlier version.

Comment: Thanks @user677779, I'll try to check an earlier version